# reactjs bootstrap media query css

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

Hello why i cannot change media query bootstrap slides when i test on mobile phone size slide goes very small and cannot see anything but when i try to add class and change it self from css only width is changing i cannot change height and some css from bootstrap is blocking mine css .

Main.css

```
import React from 'react';
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
import './css/Main.css';
import img1 from './img/slides/1.jpg'
import img2 from './img/slides/2.jpg'
import img3 from './img/slides/3.jpg'

function Main() {
  return (
    <Carousel className='slide'>
      <Carousel.Item interval={1000}>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src={img1}
          alt="First slide"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>First slide label</h3>
          <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item interval={500}>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src={img2}
          alt="Second slide"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>Second slide label</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
      <Carousel.Item>
        <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src={img3}
          alt="Third slide"
        />
        <Carousel.Caption>
          <h3>Third slide label</h3>
          <p>
            Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.
          </p>
        </Carousel.Caption>
      </Carousel.Item>
    </Carousel>
  );
}

export default Main;
```

main.css

```
@media all and (max-width: 500px) {
   .slide {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
   } 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses !important in their css classes which will override your custom classes. Try adding !important to your css declaration or try adding it inline or as an ID. IDs and inline styles are higher in the specificity hierarchy.

If that doesn't work, try using dev tools to make sure you're styling the correct element.